# Alexa testing invocation name - failed submission

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, invocation, vui

I have got a question on testing the invocation of a custom skill in Alexa.

My invocation name is let's say "merry christmas", if I type or speak it in the test section of Alexa Skills creation, LaunchRequest is triggered and conversation starts.

As soon as I submit the skill for certification, Amazon is correctly testing it with a phrase like "Alexa, launch merry christmas". In this case the LaunchRequest is not triggered.

How can I test the whole invocation name in the console? Is there any way to debug why the LaunchRequest is not triggered? Does it trigger a different intent rather that "LaunchRequest"?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tested on a echo dot device OR https://echosim.io/ OR https://reverb.ai/ ??

Comment: I can test on echosim but it would not really explain why it does not launch the LaunchRequest, does it?

Comment: Tries echosim but it currently does not support the language I am targeting, only English, German and Japanese are currently avaialble.

Comment: Is anything at all getting through to your skill? You've said your not getting a `LaunchRequest` but another request type could be coming through. If not I'd suggest this is probably because Amazon have made special use of the phrase "Merry Christmas" which is interfering with identifying your skill to the device.

Comment: Are you getting LaunchRequest in Test console

Comment: Hi Josh I was not using merry christmas :) Even though, Merry Christmas to everybody!

Comment: I wish I could give an update on this but my application is in review since 2 weeks with no feedback from Amazon. I guess I'll just keep on developing for Google Assistant... :(

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is a way to test the complete invocation phrase.

To try and debug this issue you should log your request at the app root where the request comes in, before your intent handlers are executed. This will let you see if you are receiving any request at all, and if so what it is instead of a `LaunchRequest`.